# Django: How to display details of a product in a new page when i click on a product in the product page

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am a newbie to django and i am doing a code along with a youtube tutorial on how to build an ecommerce site. My challenge right now is this: On my product page, there is a list of products. What i want is when a user clicks on a particular product, i want the user to be redirected to a page (a product details page) that has the custom details of that particular product.

This is the structure of my code.

In my views.py file, i have the 'products1' as the page view for all my products and the 'product_details' page is where i want the details of a particular product to be displayed

```
def products1(request):
products = Product.objects.all()
context = {'products':products}
return render(request, 'shopping_app/products1.html', context)

def product_details(request, id):
product = get_object_or_404(Product, id)
context = {'product': product}
return render(request, 'shopping_app/product_details.html', context)
```

In my urls.py. I created the urls for the following pages like so.

```
path('products1/', views.products1, name='products1'),
path('product_details/<int:id>', views.product_details, name='product_details'),
```

The problem is whenever i click on the product for me to be redirected to the details page, a NoReverseMatch error is thrown.

This is the error thrown

```
    NoReverseMatch at /products1/
    Reverse for 'product_details' with no arguments not found. 1 
    pattern(s) tried: ['product_details/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$']
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/products1/
    Django Version: 3.1.4
    Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
    Exception Value:    
    Reverse for 'product_details' with no arguments not found. 1 
    pattern(s) tried: ['product_details/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$']
```

*******UPDATE******
I addded the id (primary key) into the url and i am back to the TypeError being thrown

```
    {% for product in products %}
    <div class="w-52 text-left text-xs">
        <a href="{% url 'product_details' product.id %}">
            <img class="pb-2" src="{{ product.imageURL }}">
            <h4 class="opacity-90">{{product.name}}</h4>
            <span class="opacity-80">₦{{product.price|floatformat:2}}</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    {% endfor product %}
```

This is the code for my products page, The error thrown after adding the product.id to the url is as follows

```
TypeError at /product_details/1
product_details() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/product_details/1
Django Version: 3.1.4
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
product_details() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'
```

What i intend is for me to be redirected to the product details page with the information of a particular product being displayed on said page

Comment: Can you publish the full error please. I also assume that views.products4 is suppose to be views.product1

Comment: I just added the error thrown

Comment: It looks like your template is the cause of the problem and that you're not passing the ID (primary key) into the url. Could you post that please as that will help to confirm that you are passing that in.   You also need to update the call to get_object_or_404 to be get_object_or_404(Product, id=id) as otherwise you'll then trigger a different error

Comment: i passed in the id into the url and the exception error is no longer thrown rather a type error. Posting it in a bit

Comment: So now it's Shiv's answer below ```product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a million to you Mr Steve Mapes and Shiv, i really appreciate you guys taking the time out to help me out. I really do appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing id=id

```
def product_details(request, id):
product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)
context = {'product': product}
return render(request, 'shopping_app/product_details.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set a statistics object to a getter in Product.Vue, it receives assigned handiest once. If the getter modifications, the records does not trade with it: